# I want to use axios with Android build of CocosCreator

Tags: android, axios, cocoscreator

I could use axios in the browser with Cocos Creator.
But in android build I got an error.
 `ERROR: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'charAt' of undefined, location: assets/main/index.c8cc9.js:0:0`

Made this change.

```
pathname: (urlParsingNode.pathname.charAt(0) === '/') ?
urlParsingNode.pathname :
'/' + urlParsingNode.pathname
```

↓

```
pathname:urlParsingNode.pathname
```

However, no response is returned.
Only Mock returns a response.

Need to change axios source code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try add this code block

```js
if (cc.sys.isNative 
    && typeof navigator !== 'undefined' 
    && typeof navigator.product !== 'undefined') {
    Object.defineProperty(navigator, "product", {value: "NativeScript"});
}
```

Comment: In the android build of Cocos Creator, "navigator.product" was "undefined".    
`&& typeof navigator.product !== 'undefined'`
After excluding it, I was able to execute it.thanks!